# Facebook friend request using access token - android & iOS

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This question might have been asked earlier but i was not able to exactly get what i was looking for.

So in my case I have access token of user A and access token of user B with me and both are NOT friend to each other. Now i want to send friend request to user B on behalf of user A via my mobile application (assuming user A and B have already permitted app). I hope i am able to make you understand the scenario to you guys so can you please share your thoughts if it is possible and if yes then how in both iOS and android.

Regards,
MP.

Comment: You can't. There is no api for sending friends request